# Importing python project from github

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, python-3.x, github

Im trying to download [this](https://github.com/invernizzi/scapy-http) project in python from `github`
and import it to eclipse ubuntu.

The interpreter of python is 3 and I noticed that after the `git clone` and running the `setup.py`, the output is in folder `python 2.7` instead of `python 3`

And when I try to `import scapy_http.http` I get an exeption (probably the interpreter looking for it inside `python 2.7` folder).

When I try to replace the interpreter to `python 2.7` I get other exeption on `import scapy.all`

- the `import scapy` suppose to come before `import scapy_http`
- I installed scapy for python 3: `pip3 install scapy-python3`

So how can I import the `scapy-http` project to my eclipse project given the interpreter is `python 3`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ok if you did pip3 install scary-python3. It's a bit hard to tell exactly what's going on (please provide error messages, etc.) but I would suggest you try:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

If you haven't already. The problem might be that you left off the 3 and thus it was stored in python 2 libraries.